# Multiple Domains pointing to one IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS instance of a web application written in Python/Django/Java.

My domains are hosted at godaddy and we set the "A record" for www.learn.MyDomain.org to the AWS IP address. I also set the "A record" for www.learn.myOtherDomain.org at the same IP address, and now both work great.

Can I set an unlimited number of "A records" to the same IP address without causing problems?

To be clear - I want to send all domains to the default website.

Why? We would like to share our web app with other orgs, and it would be great if it appeared to their users to be owned by their own org.

Is this problematic? Are there limits?

Comment: I think that it´s possible to do it. http://superuser.com/questions/577070/is-it-possible-for-many-domain-names-to-share-one-ip-address

Comment: this belongs on a site like [sf]

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem linking a lot of domain names to the same ip address. You will however have to add the domain names in your webserver config, unless you send all domains to the default website.

This is no problem, shared hosting works on this principle.

Comment: To be clear - I want to send all domains to the default website.  Still ok?